# docker-machine on an existing, "generic" host?

Tags: docker

I have a machine on my LAN that I have SSH access to. How can I set it up so I can communicate with it using `docker-machine`?

There is a project ([boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker)) for creating ISOs that are used for new hosts, e.g. when starting a new instance with VirtualBox, Digital Ocean, etc. I would like this set up without having to nuke an already set up machine--just to run the docker-machine "node" service.

Comment: There is currently an open issue [the none driver case #2667](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2667) to figure out how `docker-machine` should allow this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

docker-machine can do it out of the box since version 0.3 using the generic driver which allows to add existing VM/host:

```
$ docker-machine create -d generic \
--generic-ssh-user ubuntu \
--generic-ssh-key ~/Downloads/manually_created_key \
--generic-ip-address 12.34.56.78 \
jungle
```

https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/

Comment: Can you provide more information on how this is possible?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include example, hopefully it makes it more helpful

Comment: Are you supposed to point to the pub key? https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/drivers/generic/generic.go#L50

Comment: You can either specify pub key or it will use ~/.ssh/id_rsa by default

Comment: and how to use this driver together with digital ocean droplets?

Comment: I think that it should point to private key, and not public. So: "--generic-ssh-key ~/Downloads/manually_created_key " without ".pub".

Comment: using generic driver to acknowledge existing machine - stops my all containers. And this is not good, because i have 5 docker-compose.yml files lying in different repo's and to start them again is a huge pain. having downtime because of generic driver doesn't make sense to me